# how to fire a function from input tag when input is not typed into it ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I'm working with angular2 color picker. The value of input element changes when color is selected from color picker and not typed. Now i have to fire a function once the value of that input tag changes.
So keyup,keydown cannot be used.
(onchange) also not working.
 [See the demo of color picker](http://alberplz.github.io/angular2-color-picker/examples/index.html)

And my template `<input [(ngModel)]="color" onblur="hexToRgb()" (keyup)="hexToRgb()" (change)="hexToRgb()"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this event `colorPickerChange`

```
<input (colorPickerChange)="color=$event" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"/>
```

two-way binding:

```
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"/>
```

Or:

```
<input [colorPicker]="color" (colorPickerChange)="color=$event" [style.background]="color" [value]="color"/>
```

Comment: i just saw the (colorPickerChange) event in the demo.Thanks, it works.